# How to access a label in datalist when a button is clicked in the same row

Tags: vb.net, datalist

I have a `DataList`, and each data list has a `label` and `button`, I want to get the text of the label when the button is clicked for each data list row ?
I am using `vb.net`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're handling the `DataList`'s [ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemcommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event by setting the Button's [CommandName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname.aspx) property.

```
 Sub Item_Command(sender As Object, e As DataListCommandEventArgs)Handles DataList1.ItemCommand

    ' What command was triggered?
    If e.CommandName = "YourCommandName" Then

        ' Get the Label in the DataListItem of the clicked button
        Dim lbl = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("Label1"), Label)
        Dim labelText = lbl.Text
    End If

 End Sub
```